# bash getopts options for different functions

Tags: bash, getopts

how can I make this work? I want to use different functions for my command, my problem is how can I pass arguments to the `add.sh` function? `find.sh` works fine but the first two commands says no arg for `-v` / `-a` option. What am I doing wrong?

```
while getopts v:a:s opt
do
case "$opt" in

v) ./view.sh;;

a) ./add.sh;;

s) ./find.sh;;
```

Comment: What is the question here exactly? You've told `getopts` that the `-v` and `-a` options require arguments. Are you passing arguments to that script? If you do that you shouldn't get an error from `getopts`. You also seem to be asking how to pass that argument (or other arguments?) to the called function. Those are two very different questions. The first is answered, in part, by reading how `getopts` works. The second is answered by not running the script until you've assembled all the arguments.

Comment: I'm trying to pass arguments to the -v and -a scripts, I'm not really sure is the scripts are right to receive arguments, heres the script for view.sh


(awk -F ";" '{printf "Record: %d\n\t%s\n\t%s\n\t%s, %s, %s\n\t%s\n==========================\n\n", NR, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}' $BOOK ; echo "Press Q to Quit and return to the menu." ) | less

Comment: I do have a toplevel script where I can run all scripts just fine, but  I'm struggling with getops. I have toplevel.sh script to run all other scripts, now I'm trying to make another script just for the getops, I set it up that when there is no arguments supplied the getops script automatically opens the toplevel script. I'm still trying to learn it. Thanks for helping sir

Comment: How are you calling your toplevel script? What argument to that `view.sh` script are you expecting to pass it from the toplevel script `$BOOK`? You call scripts with arguments the same way you pass arguments to commands at the shell, you just put them on the command line.

Comment: I'm still experimenting sir, thanks for the answers though, I'd like to commend you but don't know how..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the `-v` option onto the `view.sh` script, then do so:

```
while getopts v:a:s opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    v) ./view.sh -v "$OPTARG";;
    a) ./add.sh -a "$OPTARG";;
    s) ./find.sh;;
    esac
done
```

If you want to pass the 'other' arguments to `view.sh` too, then you have to work a bit harder.  You could simply pass all the arguments with `./view.sh "$@";;` but being selective is harder.